# SVN directly to tar

Tags: svn, tar, gzip, packages

Is there a way to directly tar the latest version of an SVN folder without the SVN hidden files? I would like to create a tar archive without the SVN files. I know you can get the latest with the SVN tracking files, but is there a one liner that will directly send the information to an archive?

Comment: I don't know about svn, but github allows you to download .tar.gzs of a git repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to make a copy of the latest version of a repository without all the .svn folders is to use the `svn export` command.

Here's how I would make the archive:

```
$ svn export URL PATH ; tar czf exported_copy.tgz PATH
```

Where URL is the URL of your svn repository and PATH is a local path suitable for saving a copy of the exported repository. I don't know a way to do it more directly than this. Unfortunately you do end up with the exported copy hanging around, so you might just want to put the whole thing in a short bash script which then deletes the temp files afterwards.

EDIT: While this is the easiest method and is what I used as well I would be careful. In my research I found this 
http://narfation.org/2009/01/08/creating-recreatable-tar-gz-from-svn
which clearly tells us the problem of preserved group/user ownership which causes problems when deploying to another system. I have tried this script with modifications of my own to suit my purpose and you might benefit as well.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe version 1.23 of tar allows you to exclude all versioning files from command line but unfortunately don't work on my 1.20 version:

```
tar --exclude-vcs -cvzf archive.tar.gz directory/
```

Comment: Very nice!  I didn't know about [that option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/exclude.html#IDX406).

Answer (score 4):

Go to the subversion working directory (checkout) and run this:

```
find -name .svn -prune -o -print | cpio -o -H tar | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

If you're using GNU utilities you can also run:

```
find -name .svn -prune -o -print0 | cpio -o -0 -H tar | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

If possible, I would recommend using the *ustar* format (`-H ustar`).

Answer (score 3):

I see as well:

```
tar cvfz archive.tar.gz directory/  --exclude='*/.svn'
```

Thanks tar.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to tar the results of an svn checkout?

So, in pseudocode, it'd look something like this:

```
svn export branch; find branch | grep -v '/.' | xargs cp tarbranch ; tar -zcf tarbranch.tgz tarbranch
```

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from a one-liner I wrote. It assumes you have a ~/tmp directory. You'll need to change the PROJ and URL variables in the first two steps. The rest should work.

For easy copying:

```
PROJ='yourproj' && URL='http://svn.example.com/svn/repo/$PROJ' && REV=`svn info $URL | fgrep Revision | cut -d ' ' -f 2` &&  cd ~/tmp &&  svn export $URL $PROJ && tar czv -f $PROJ.r$REV.tar.gz $PROJ && rm -r $PROJ.r$REV
```

For easy viewing:

```
PROJ='yourproj' && 
URL='http://svn.example.com/svn/repo/$PROJ' && 
REV=`svn info $URL | fgrep Revision | cut -d ' ' -f 2` &&  
cd ~/tmp && 
svn export $URL $PROJ && 
tar czv -f $PROJ.r$REV.tar.gz $PROJ && 
rm -r $PROJ.r$REV
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my effort of trying to make a deterministic tarball from an SVN repo.

Requires GNU tar 1.27 or later.

Features:

- Deterministic tarball
- Timestamp precision in microseconds from SVN, thanks to `pax` extended header
- Revision ID stored in archive comments just like [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) would do
- I demonstrate both `.tar.gz` and `.tar.xz` compressions. For gzip, you may optimize the compression further by using [`advdef`](http://www.advancemame.it/doc-advdef) from [AdvanceCOMP](http://www.advancemame.it/comp-readme) (`advdef` uses zopfli library).

As an example, I use subversion repo itself as a source for checkout and
creation of the tarball. Note that this isn't the way SVN package their
tarballs and I'm no way related to SVN development. It's just an *example*,
after all.

```
# URL of repository to export
url="https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.9.7/"
# Name of distribution sub-directory
dist_name=subversion-1.9.7-test
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

info=$(svn info --xml "$url" | tr -- '\t\n' '  ')
revision=$(echo "$info" |
    sed 's|.*<commit[^>]* revision="\{0,1\}\([^">]*\)"\{0,1\}>.*|\1|')
tar_name=${dist_name}-r${revision}
# Subversion's commit timestamps can be as precise as 0.000001 seconds,
# but sub-second precision is only available through --xml output
# format.
date=$(echo "$info" |
    sed 's|.*<commit[^>]*>.*<date>\([^<]*\)</date>.*</commit>.*|\1|')

# Factors that would make tarball non-deterministic include:
# - umask
# - Ordering of file names
# - Timestamps of directories ("svn export" doesn't update them)
# - User and group names and IDs
# - Format of tar (gnu, ustar or pax)
# - For pax format, the name and contents of extended header blocks

umask u=rwx,go=rx
svn export -r "$revision" "$url" "$dist_name"
# "svn export" will update file modification time to latest time of
# commit that modifies the file, but won't do so on directories.
find . -type d | xargs touch -c -m -d "$date" --

trap 's=$?; rm -f "${tar_name}.tar" || : ; exit $s' 1 2 3 15
# pax extended header allows sub-second precision on modification time.
# The default extended header name pattern ("%d/PaxHeaders.%p/%f")
# would contain a process ID that makes tarball non-deterministic.
# "git archive" would store a commit ID in pax global header (named
# "pax_global_header"). We can do similar.
# GNU tar (<=1.30) has a bug that it rejects globexthdr.mtime that
# contains fraction of seconds.
pax_options=$(printf '%s%s%s%s%s%s' \
    "globexthdr.name=pax_global_header," \
    "globexthdr.mtime={$(echo ${date}|sed -e 's/\.[0-9]*Z/Z/g')}," \
    "comment=${revision}," \
    "exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f," \
    "delete=atime," \
    "delete=ctime")
find "$dist_name" \
    \( -type d -exec printf '%s/\n' '{}' \; \) -o -print |
    LC_ALL=C sort |
    tar -c --no-recursion --format=pax --owner=root:0 --group=root:0 \
    --pax-option="$pax_options" -f "${tar_name}.tar" -T -

# Compression (gzip/xz) can add additional non-deterministic factors.
# xz format does not store file name or timestamp...
trap 's=$?; rm -f "${tar_name}.tar.xz" || : ; exit $s' 1 2 3 15
xz -9e -k "${tar_name}.tar"

# ...but for gzip, you need either --no-name option or feed the input
# from stdin. This example uses former, and also tries advdef to
# optimize compression if available.
trap 's=$?; rm -f "${tar_name}.tar.gz" || : ; exit $s' 1 2 3 15
gzip --no-name -9 -k "${tar_name}.tar" &&
{ advdef -4 -z "${tar_name}.tar.gz" || : ; }
```